# How can I send data from one page to another using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm using laravel 5.1 and I'm stuck in a weird situation.

I have 2 models `Season`and `Tournament` and lets say the url to add a `Season` model is `..../seasons/add` and to view the season would be `..../seasons/(id)`... standard stuff right?

But now I want to add a tournament from the link `..../seasons/1` and so I click a link that takes me to `..../tournaments/add`... how can I send the `Season` model to that page without submitting a form with hidden input?

Currently I have this setup `..../seasons/1/tournaments/add` using blade to generate the links. But this method just doesn't feel right....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I send data from one page to another using Laravel?*: I would suggest that you do this from your controller. Take a look at [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects), it might come in handy.

From the [Flash Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data) documentation: "[...] it will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted [...]"

You can send your model, static values or whatever you want using ->with:

```
redirect('route')->with('key', 'value');
```