# How can I send a user defined data from one page to another in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

P.S -I am not going to use `Session Flash` as answered by someone [in a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040740/how-can-i-send-data-from-one-page-to-another-using-laravel).

I have a page which lets a user select if s/he has selected Value  1 or Value 2. Based on that, the user will be sent to another page, which will be sent to another page.

Here is my blade

**Page 1**

```
<select id="type" name="type">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<a href="{{url('page2')}}">Click Here</a>
```

**Page 2**

```
You have selected {{$type}}  <-------- Value 1/Value 2
```

But, I am not sure how to get the data in page 2.

Comment: How you reach the `page1` to `page2`? you have a controller between `page1` and `page2` , right? Like : **Page1 => Controller => Page2**, then you can `reflash` by `$request->session()->reflash();` or with `$request->session()->keep(['type', 'type value']);` the method is describe here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data

Comment: I dont want to use flash, like I said

Comment: @EsTeAa Can't I send it via URL. I dont know the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple HTML form.

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('page2') }}">
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

So then, on page 2 you can do `{{ $type }}` only if you have a controller like:

```php
public function show(Request $request) {
    return view('name_of_view_for_page_2', ['type' => $request->input('type')]);
}
```

Comment: What if I send `1` or `2` to the next page in the URL itself, and access that respetive value. I dont know the syntax though

Comment: How will you do that ? You will need Javascript, like `location.href = http://url_2?type=1` or something like that... You need to explain more what you really need and why you can't use `flash`.

Comment: If I use flash, and the user refreshes the page, the data will be lost. I dont want that

Comment: So, you want to store the info in the session. Read how to [put](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data) data in the session and how to [read](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-data) it.